# Install Windows Service using chef and have it run using a Group Managed Service Account

Tags: chef, managed-service-accounts

I'm trying to setup a number of dev servers using Chef. I need a Windows Service to run as a managed service account. I have the following in a recipe:

```
windows_service 'My Windows Service' do
    action :create
    display_name "My Windows Service"
    service_name "MyWindowsService"
    binary_path_name "c:\\Program Files\\MyWindowsService\\MyService.exe"
    startup_type :automatic
    delayed_start true
    run_as_user "Domain\\MyGMSA$"
    description "Describes my service"
end
```

This registers the service just fine, but it sets the logon to "Local System account". Is there something else that I need to specify to make it work?

Comment: What's your chef version?  A lot is different with the windows resources between 12, 13, and 14.

Comment: @Colyn1337 we're running 14.7.17